# Format string array to custom string

Tags: java

this should be an easy one. I need to format a string array if the length is greater than 1 to look as following:  "('STRING','STRING')

Thanx

```
if  (form.getSorCodes().length > 1)

            for( int i=0;i<form.getSorCodes().length;i++)
             {

                 //format here         

             }
```

Comment: Use StringBuffer to build up the string. One word of advice (given that I have no idea what sort of system this snippet is from) in theory getSorCodes() could be a time consuming operation, or the results may change between the 2 calls, so you are better off storing it's return value rather than calling it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[] sorCodes = form.getSorCodes();
if  (sorCodes.length > 1) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("(");
    for( int i=0;i<sorCodes.length;i++) { 
       builder.append("'").append(sorCodes[i]).append("'");
       if(i < sorCodes.length - 1) {
          builder.append(",");
       }
    }
    builder.append(")");

    builder.toString(); //('STRING','STRING') 
}
```

Comment: Thanx mate..bout to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("(");
Joiner.on(',').appendTo(result, stringArray);
return result.append(",").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this Class:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
```